# Why is will_paginate gem returning all results to one page but showing next and previous links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, will-paginate

I've spent the last few hours finding out why will_paginate wouldn't work on my user account area page "site.com/" (users/new) but would work on other pages such as site.com/search, site.com/browse.

Is there any way to deal with my current issue? The user account area page is the same page the user signs up on but with the signup content hidden. It is my root path (site.com/).

The next and previous links show but all results are displayed on one page.

**Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper
  include MessagesHelper

  def new
    @user = User.new 
    if logged_in?
      @current_user = User.find_by_username(current_user.username)
      @default_photo = Photo.find(current_user.profile.photo_id) if current_user.profile.photo_id
      @micropost = Micropost.new(:user_id => users_id)
      @microposts = current_user.microposts.page(params[:page]).per_page(1)
      @default_image = default_profile_image
      @comment = Comment.new(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

**HTML/HAML:**

```
.microposts
  = render 'users/partials/micropost_form'
  - if @current_user.microposts.any?            
    = render 'users/partials/microposts'
    = will_paginate @microposts
```

**Some of my microposts partial**

```
<% @current_user.microposts.each do |m| %>
        <% if m.poster_id.nil? %>
       <div class="postHolder">
        <nav class="micropostOptions">
         <ul class="postMenu">
           <li class="deletePost"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Delete post"), m, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :title => m.content, :class => "message_delete" %>
           </li>
           <li class="disableCommenting"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Pause commenting"), "2" %></li>
           <li class="blockCommenter"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Block commenter"), "3" %></li>
           <li class="openInNewWindow"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Open in new window"), "4" %></li>
           <li class="reportAbuse"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Report abuse"), "5" %></li>
         </ul>  
       </nav>
```

#### Update

Hmm, I just created a separate action in my users controller called `microposts` gave it its own route and view then tried will_paginate on that page but it still returns all results on one page. Confused

Comment: Take a look at your partial `users/partials/microposts`. I'd bet that you're referring to `@current_user.microposts` or equivalent (which is not paginated), rather than `@microposts` (which is).

I would probably be inclined to make the partial take an object argument, and then pass it a `:collection` option.

Comment: You're right, I'm referring to @current_user.microposts in my partial (added to post). Why would you need to make the partial take an object argument? Just trying to understand.

Comment: You don't need to in your case. If the partial might be used in a controller where `@microposts` wasn't declared (but you had some form of micropost data from elsewhere), passing it in to the partial explicitly might be more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed thanks to Jeremy's comment above. I changed my partial so that it would refer to @microposts instead of @current_user.microposts and my problem was solved. Don't know how I could miss that.